# YugaByte DB services gets down when any of the yb-tserver stops working

Tags: yugabytedb

I am new to Yugabyte DB i have 6 pods given below names and states . One pod yb-tserver-3  is in CrashLoopBackOff state .Now i am not able to connect to my DB through DBeaver as i am getting error1 :- FATAL: Remote error: Service unavailable (yb/rpc/service_pool.cc:223): OpenTable request on yb.tserver.PgClientService from [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:xxxx dropped due to backpressure

error2 :- connection timeout

yb-master-0                                  2/2     Running            0          24h
yb-master-1                                  2/2     Running            0          24h
yb-master-2                                  2/2     Running            0          23h
yb-tserver-0                                 2/2     Running            230        14d
yb-tserver-1                                 2/2     Running            0          25h
yb-tserver-2                                 2/2     Running            0          23h
yb-tserver-3                                 1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   4          6m33s

Now my question is if my one of the yb-tserver is down my yugabyte db services should be up and running but here my db is down and rejecting application connectivity and Dbeaver connectivity . How can i resolve this issue i have seen many times if one tablet servers stops working all connectivity gets lost.

please help me out.

Comment: How did you deploy the cluster? 
Why do you have "2/2" on all servers? 
What are the vcpu/memory of each pod?

Comment: we have deployed it through helm chart 

1) our memory size details are given below 

 
   Limits:
      cpu:     3
      memory:  4Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  4Gi

And we are getting above error because of time difference between pods (CrashLoopBackOff)

Comment: its urgent please help on this

Comment: please come ask on slack, stackoverflow is not the right medium for this